# error null al llamar una clase dentro de otra clase secundaria y principal java

Tags: java, null

hola tengo un problema tengo que realizar un programa el cual debo realizar con 3 clases.
1 operaciones básicas
2 triangulo y
3 el programa que va a mandar a imprimir todo llamado principal
el problema me surge cuando mando a llamar a la clase operaciones desde la clase triangulo me sale este error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Triangulo.area(Triangulo.java:101)
        at Principal.main(Principal.java:25)
```

supuesta mente este error es por que hay datos nulos o algo así
Nota: no se casi nada de programación en java si me pueden explicar a detalle se los agradecería.
les adjunto el código de los 3 archivos

```
class Operaciones_Basicas{
    // Variables - Atributos

    /* ENCAPSULAMIENTO */
    private int dato_1;
    private int dato_2;

    private float dato_1_float;
    private float dato_2_float;

    // CONSTRUCTORES
    Operaciones_Basicas(){
        this.dato_1 = 0;
        this.dato_2 = 0;
        this.dato_1_float = 0.0f;
        this.dato_2_float = 0.0f;
    }
    // Esto ya es Polimorfismo
    Operaciones_Basicas(int dato_1, int dato_2, float dato_1_float, float dato_2_float){
        this.dato_1 = dato_1;
        this.dato_2 = dato_2;
        this.dato_1_float = dato_1_float;
        this.dato_2_float = dato_2_float;
    }

    // Setters and Getters
    int getDato_1(){
        return dato_1;
    }

    void setDato_1(int dato_1){
        this.dato_1 = dato_1;
    }

    int getDato_2(){
        return dato_2;
    }

    void setDato_2(int dato_2){
        this.dato_2 = dato_2;
    }

    float getDato_FLoat_1(){
        return dato_1_float;
    }

    void setDato_Float_1(float dato_1_float){
        this.dato_1_float = dato_1_float;
    }

    float getDato_FLoat_2(){
        return dato_2_float;
    }

    void setDato_Float_2(float dato_2_float){
        this.dato_2_float = dato_2_float;
    }

    // Metodos - Acciones
    int suma(){
        // Simplificar
        return dato_1 + dato_2;
    }

    // Sobrecarga del metodo suma
    int suma(int dato_1, int dato_2){
        return dato_1 + dato_2;
    }

    int resta(){
        return dato_1 - dato_2;
    }

    // Sobrecarga del metodo resta
    int resta(int dato_1, int dato_2){
        return dato_1 - dato_2;
    }

    int multiplicacion(){
        return dato_1 * dato_2;
    }

    // Sobrecarga del metodo multiplicacion
    int multiplicacion(int dato_1, int dato_2){
        return dato_1 * dato_2;
    }   

    float division(){
        return dato_1_float / dato_2_float;
    }

    // Sobrecarga del metodo division
    float division(float dato_1_float, float dato_2_float){
        return dato_1_float / dato_2_float;
    }   
}
```

```
public class Triangulo {
    /*
    Variables
    */
    private int L_a, L_b, L_c, h_altura;    
    private Float l_AFloat, l_BFloat, l_CFloat,h_alturafFloat;
    Operaciones_Basicas Opera;
  

    Triangulo() {
        this.L_a = 5;
        this.L_b = 5;
        this.h_altura = 8;
        this.L_c=4;
        this.l_AFloat = 5.2f;
        this.l_BFloat = 5.4f;
        this.l_CFloat = 8.6f;
        this.h_alturafFloat=8.4f;

    }
    Triangulo(Float l_AFloat, Float l_BFloat, Float h_alturafFloat, Float  l_CFloat) {
        this.h_alturafFloat = h_alturafFloat;
        this.l_CFloat=l_CFloat;
        this.l_AFloat = l_AFloat;   
        this.l_BFloat = l_BFloat;
    }


    Triangulo(int L_a, int L_b, int h_altura, int  L_c) {
        this.h_altura = h_altura;
        this.L_c=L_c;
        this.L_a = L_a; 
        this.L_b = L_b;        
    }
    // Setters and Getters enteros
    int getL_a(){
        return L_a;
    }

    void setL_a(int L_a){
        this.L_a = L_a;
    }

    int getL_b(){
        return L_b;
    }

    void setL_b(int L_b){
        this.L_b = L_b;
    }
    int getL_c(){
        return L_c;
    }
    void setL_c(int L_c){
        this.L_c = L_c;
    }

    int geth_altura(){
        return h_altura;
    }

    void seth_altura(int h_altura){
        this.h_altura = h_altura;
    }
    
    

    // Setters and Getters Flotantes
    Float getL_AFloat(){
        return l_AFloat;
    }

    void setL_AFloat(Float l_AFloat){
        this.l_AFloat = l_AFloat;
    }

    Float getL_BFloat(){
        return l_BFloat;
    }

    void setL_b(Float l_BFloat){
        this.l_BFloat = l_BFloat;
    }
    float getL_CFloat(){
        return l_CFloat;
    }
    void setL_c(Float l_CFloat){
        this.l_CFloat = l_CFloat;
    }

    float geth_h_alturafFloat(){
        return h_alturafFloat;
    }

    void seth_h_alturafFloat(Float h_alturafFloat){
        this.h_alturafFloat = h_alturafFloat;
    }
    //metodos

    int area(int h_altura ,int L_b){   
      int a= Opera.multiplicacion(h_altura, L_b);
      int result= a/2;
      return result;
       
    }
    int area(){
        int resultado=0;
        return resultado;
    }
    
}
```

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangulo obj = new Triangulo();
        //Imprecion de datos Enteros y flotantes
        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("                  Datos enteros      ");
        System.out.println("*****************************************\n");
        System.out.println("Lado a = "+ obj.getL_a());
        System.out.println("Lado b = "+ obj.getL_b());
        System.out.println("Lado c = "+ obj.getL_c());
        System.out.println("Altura = "+ obj.geth_altura());
        System.out.println("\n*****************************************");
        System.out.println("                  Datos Flotantes      ");
        System.out.println("*****************************************\n");
        System.out.println("Lado a = "+ obj.getL_AFloat());
        System.out.println("Lado b = "+ obj.getL_BFloat());
        System.out.println("Lado c = "+ obj.getL_CFloat());
        System.out.println("Altura = "+ obj.geth_h_alturafFloat());

        //imprecion de area y perimetro

        System.out.println("\n*****************************************");
        System.out.println("                  Area      ");
        System.out.println("*****************************************\n");
        System.out.println(obj.area(3, 2));


        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("                  Perimetro      ");
        System.out.println("*****************************************");

    }
}
```

Nota2: se que seria mas facil Realizar operaciones nuevas pero es necesario ocupar las 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no estas inicializando la variable **`Opera`**, realizalo de esta forma:

```
int area(int h_altura ,int L_b){   
  Operaciones_Basicas Opera = new Operaciones_Basicas(); 
  int a= Opera.multiplicacion(h_altura, L_b);
  int result= a/2;
  return result;
   
}
```